# Avoiding "junk after document element" for jQuery .ajax with datatype: 'text'?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting "junk after document element" when trying to load a file via jQuery `ajax` call. This answer from 2010 [Xml Calling with jQuery, (invalid XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381128/xml-calling-with-jquery-invalid-xml) seems to suggest that `dataType: "text"` instead of `dataType: "xml",` should fix it, but that doesn't work for me.

Here is the test I run locally on Firefox ( "[I think Firefox permits access to local files via XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file)", "[Firefox can disabled that within it's `about:config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files)" ):

**`test.txt`**

```
  <option value='1'>Hello</option>
  <option value='2'>World</option>
```

**`test.htm`**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax ({
    url: 'test.txt',
    data: {},
    type: 'get',
    datatype: 'text', // 'html', // "junk after document element" seems to be caused by both text and html?
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(result) {
      if (jQuery.type(result) == "object") {
        console.log("[none?!]");
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      console.log("ERROR: " + xhr.status + " / " + thrownError + " / " + xhr.responseText);
    }
  }); // end ajax
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The response in Firefox 39 Browser Console is:

```
"ERROR: 200 / Error: Invalid XML:   <option value='1'>Hello</option>
  <option value='2'>World</option>
 /   <option value='1'>Hello</option>
  <option value='2'>World</option>
" test.htm:20:7
junk after document element test.txt:2:3
junk after document element test.htm:2:3
```

The weird thing is, I *explicitly* state `datatype: 'text'` just so that JavaScript avoids parsing this string as XML - and yet it still attempts to do so, and fails? Why is this, and how can I get the AJAX call ***not*** to parse the response as HTML/XML?

---

EDIT: Thanks to @JAAulde's comment, now I know I've made a spelling mistake; so when I try with the correct case:

```
    dataType: 'text',
```

... now at least the read doesn't register as an error - the console log is:

```
"  <option value='1'>Hello</option>
  <option value='2'>World</option>
" test.htm:16:9
junk after document element test.txt:2:3
```

... but I'm still getting "junk after document element"; can this somehow be avoided?

Comment: The option is `dataType` (camel cased), not `datatype`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for that, @JAAulde - sorry I cannot yet upvote `:)` Indeed I had a spelling mistake (posted update in OP), and I think that solves the general breakage, but I'm still getting the "...junk..." message...